# HTML Form method PUT with ServiceStack

Tags: html, servicestack

I have written a PUT method in my ServiceStack API. The method updates a piece of equipment in a database.

I have tested the method with Fiddler and it does exactly what I want... Happy Days!

Then, I have realised that with html Forms you can only use a method of GET & POST so I cannot do a PUT from a web form....

Reading around a bit a number of people appear to be saying to add:

```
<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="put" />
```

But when I debug the api it still goes to the GET function and not the PUT.

At the moment I am trying to use this:

```
<form action="/equipment/DP112" method="put">
        <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="put" />
        <input name="description" type="text" value="" />
        <input type="submit" value="Update description on DP112" />
</form>
```

Which when I look in Fiddler looks like this:

```
GET http://localhost:19323/equipment/DP112?description=abc HTTP/1.1
Accept: text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*
Referer: http://localhost:19323/default.htm
Accept-Language: en-GB,en;q=0.5
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: Keep-Alive
DNT: 1
Host: localhost:19323
```

Obviously I have done something wrong... How should I have dealt with this?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

turns out I needed this:

```
<input name="X-HTTP-Method-Override" type="hidden" value="PUT" />
```

not

```
<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="put" />
```

worked perfect.